# Architecture solution in accessing same table by many modules

Tags: database, architecture

For example, many modules access table T directly using user query.

I think this is quite wrong architecture. I want to know what is wrong in architecture and solution

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of dependency - if you make a change in that table each and every module that use it will have to be updated.

Another potential problem (you didn't specify anything about how this table is used) is that multiple modules can make changes to the table and then it might get to inconsistent state (logically, though that can be somewhat mitigated with transactions)

Yet another problem is that the table can be a contention point and cause performance problems

There are a few other problems that can occur like scale,  or too many responsibilities etc. but you'd really need to supply more details about your situation for a more specific answer

Comment: In my case, at least three modules reference one table and we have to delete a column in a table because this column is equal with combination of other three columns in a table.
However, if I delete this column, all modules should change its code and queries.
I know the architecture is wrong, but I can't find a solution to fix it.
I am willing to change the DB structure if I have to change the structure.
Thanks.

Comment: for your situation it might be easiest to create one or more views on top of the table that retain the old structure and then you can take the time to migrate your various modules (or think about refactoring the overall solution)

Comment: Thanks. If I create a view on the table and related tables, I can take the time to migration all codes.